# SQL Server : ignore strings in SUM function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sum

I do a `sum` function over a column. But the column can have string values also. I want SQL Server to ignore the string values and sum only the string values.

Eg: column can have values like 16000Euro or 2588, or 3671.

The input is from user and I cant change validation in the app to integer

I have tried this but still shows error:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Type_New = 202 AND ISNUMERIC(Summe) = 1 
       THEN Summe 
       ELSE 0 
    END) AS total_Euro
```

So how can I ignore the string values when doing sum operation?

The error I get is:

> Error converting nvarchar value '2588. 'in the int data type.

EDIT: I want SQL to ignore such string values and sum what it can.. The main aim is that Query should not throw any error

Comment: Please post the error. Name SUM a field is not good

Comment: use numeric types for numeric data.

Comment: So basically the problem is that SELECT ISNUMERIC('2588.'); returns a 1.  This means most of the answers below won't work.

Comment: @RichardHansell yeah you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below Query, it will work perfectly :)

```
   SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Type_New = 202 AND ISNUMERIC(Summe + '.0e0') = 1 
           THEN Summe 
           ELSE 0 
        END) AS total_Euro FROM TableName
```

IsNumeric returns 1 if the varchar value can be converted to ANY number type (includes int, bigint, decimal, numeric, real & float) Values like 1e4,1., 2.0 will create the issue if the above check to bypass these values is not added.

Answer (score 0):

You should not name column same as a keyword in SQL Server , if this cannot be avoided you can escape column name by enclosing in square bracketes `[Sum]` as shown below

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 202 AND ISNUMERIC([Sum]) = 1 THEN [Sum] ELSE 0 END) AS total_Euro
```

Comment: i modified the column name for question..column name is not the the problem here.. i know you can escape with square brackets

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 202 AND case when Sum not like '%[^0-9]%' THEN Sum END ELSE 0 END) AS total_Euro
```

or

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 202 AND ISNUMERIC(Sum+'.e0') = 1 THEN Sum ELSE 0 END) AS total_Euro
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SUM (CASE 
     WHEN Type_New = 202 AND ISNUMERIC(Summe) = 1 THEN CAST(summe AS DECIMAL(9,2))
     ELSE 0 END) AS TotalEuro
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you do this `SUM` for one column or what, but also you can filter out what you need and then sum:

```
SELECT SUM(Summe) AS total_Euro
FROM someTable
WHERE Type_New = 202 AND ISNUMERIC(Summe) = 1
```

Comment: Hope this should be the straight forwards simple answer

Comment: i tried ISNUMERIC in where still shows the same error.. even i thought that this should work

Comment: this won't work as Sum function cannot work on `nvarchar-Summe` column .. you will have to convert it to correct data type int..

Answer (score 0):

`ISNUMERIC` function considers strings that contain `large numeric` (e.g., 9223372036854775808), `decimals` (e.g., 12.4), `currency figures` (e.g., $123), and `floating-point values` (e.g., 1E2) to be strings that can be converted to a numeric data type.

Now to calculate `Sum` you will have to convert `string` to an `integer`[ this assumption is based on
sample data you have posted] but fact is string can be numeric but might not be convertible to an integer; the ISNUMERIC function is limited in the sense that it can tell you only whether the string can be converted to any numeric data type.

So if your column doesn't have string data like `1E3` or `12.4` or `$123` which are `numeric` but not `integers`  you can simply cast the target column to int as below and calculate the sum :

```
select SUM(CASE WHEN Type_New = 202 AND ISNUMERIC(Summe) = 1 
       THEN CAST(Summe AS INT)  
       ELSE 0 
    END) AS total_Euro
FROM test
```

else you shoudl go for a more generic function which as discussed here..
http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/can-i-convert-string-integer

Comment: the column does contains values like 15000Euro or 1234.1 or 10000€

Comment: yeah that's a catch for ISNUMERIC() function..so you want to consider these columns while calculating sum or not???

Comment: no I just want sql to ignore such string values and just sum what it can.. so that the query does not throw an error..

Comment: you want to consider 1234.1 or 10000€ for summation for `total_Euro`?

Comment: I update such values to be in integer form later.. i just want sql to ignore such values